# Data availability statement for a mathematics paper

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I am submitting a mathematics paper and was informed that I need to add a "data availability statement." However, this isn't a paper for a medical journal or anything that analyzes data. There isn't even any data to make available! Should I just put down something like, "No new data were created or analyzed in this study. Data sharing is not applicable to this article"? I contacted the person from the editorial office, but she was more or less useless and just rehashed that I needed to include a data availability statement.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The journal probably expects some boilerplate statement. For example, Springer Nature have some [suggestions](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/research-data-policy/data-availability-statements/12330880), such as

> All data generated or analysed during this study are included in this published article (and its supplementary information files).

or

> Data sharing not applicable to this article as no datasets were generated or analysed during the current study.

You could also check comparable papers from the same journal or publisher to see if there is any standard statement. Overall, there are often sweeping policies to include data availability statements etc., and it becomes one of those bureaucratic things where a field needs to be filled out even when it doesn't make sense. Hence boilerplates.

Comment: Thanks. I'll use the second one because that seems most accurate.